# Save google sheet chart to google drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have a table chart which gets updated(the range) using a function. I want to save the chart as png to drive but it fails on chart.getBlob() with Service error:...
The chart range is changing..I dnt know why I cant get the blob.

```
var chart = chartSheet.getCharts()[0]; 
  var currentRange = chart.getRanges()[0];  
  chart = chart.modify()
    .removeRange(currentRange)
    .addRange(chartRange)
    .setPosition(2,2,0,0)
    .build();
  chartSheet.updateChart(chart);



   var blob = chart.getBlob();
   var driveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1ktaP4r2da8loDOWU-xjcHzArpC0zcr1H');

   var file = driveFolder.createFile(blob);
```

Comment: In my environment, unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation. So in order to replicate your situation, can you provide the whole script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031833/google-apps-script-fails-to-generate-image-from-embeddedchartbuilder), this is due to a bug in Spreadsheets. You may check this [bug reported](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5549).